# Отображение истории гит истории саб-модулей в Rider

Tags: rider

В общем, есть C# Solution и туда подключен, как саб-модуль проект.

Когда я захожу в какой-нибудь файл саб-модуля и хочу посмотреть историю, то Rider мне ничего не отображает.

В Rider есть возможность работать с саб-модулями - создавать новые ветки, переключать их и т.д в рамках основного решения? Если да, то как это делается?